# Fastest way to do name value pair look up for a long list

Tags: php, arrays, loops, logic, namevaluecollection

I'm working with a long list of name - value pairs and I will be checking with this list alot so I wanted to know what you guys think is the fastest way to do named value pair look ups. An example of my problem is as follows:

Using PHP

The variables are on the left side with the string value they are suppose to represent. There are roughly 68 variable with corresponding string values.

```
rKid = Hiking
rSpo = Sports
rFly = Flying
```

I will need a look up every web page to see what each of the variables could correspond to. 
I was thinking of an array -> list value look up, but unsure of how to implement that.

Comment: Why aren't regular php arrays helpful in that case?

Comment: Have you tried using `array_keys()` to get all the keys, and `in_array()` to check if something is in the array? You could also just use `array_key_exists()` to see if a certain key exists. If you need to walk through the entire array, then a `foreach` is what you're looking for.

Comment: With only 68 values, I don't think "speed" is a big consideration. Write code that you understand, and can maintain...

Comment: ill give array_keys() a try

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 in_array together with array_keys is both overcomplicated and inefficient while array_key_exists does exactly the same with a simple lookup. But I don't see how it helps the requirement to **see what each of the variables could correspond to**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associative arrays in PHP are in fact hash maps, so lookup by key is very efficient. What you need is this structure:

```
$map = array(
    'rKid' => 'Hiking',
    'rSpo' => 'Sports,'
    'rFly' => 'Flying'
);
```

And the lookup is straightforward:

```
echo $map['rKid']; // 'Hiking'
```